# TypeORM CLI is not generating migrations when using it with type-graphql

Tags: node.js, typescript, graphql, typeorm, typegraphql

I wanted to use [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io) together with [TypeGraphQL](https://typegraphql.ml).

TypeGraphQL even has an [example](https://github.com/19majkel94/type-graphql/tree/master/examples/typeorm-basic-usage) for this case.

But when I use it like that and try to generate migrations from that (using the TypeORM CLI and running `migration:generate`), nothing happens.

There is no error in the log, no other log, nothing.

This is the command I’m running:

`ts-node -P tsconfig.typeorm.json --log-error -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n UserEntity`

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4361

Comment: At the example in index.ts file you can see this option:  " dropSchema: true". I think database is dropped each time you run the app. This is the reason because you are not getting error messages.